# How to inherit a model object instead of the model class

Tags: django, django-models

For some reasons, I want my Boolean Fields in my `class Items(models.Model)` to have a foreign key in my `class ItemsGotten(models.Model)`. Here's my code for better understanding...

````
Items(models.Model):
    title=models.Charfield(max_length=180)
    description=models.Textfield(max_length=180)
    paper=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    skin=models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

ItemsGotten(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paperitem  = models.ForeignKey(???)
    skinitem  = models.ForeignKey(???)```
````

I know that you can simply get the value of the whole model class e.g `paperitem  = models.ForeignKey(Items)`. But that's not what I want to achieve, I want to get only the object from the Items model. e.g `skinitem  = models.ForeignKey(Items.skin)`. Thanks

Comment: `skin` is a `BooleanField`, an *not* unique, so that means that the `ForeignKey` would not refer to a unique `Items` object. It does not make much sense to do this, since then `skinitem` would simply be a `BooleanField`.

Comment: It thus does not make any sense, if you want to access the `paper` or `skin` field of the related `Items`, you use a `ForeignKey` to `Item`, and then access it with `self.item.paper` for example. You can also use `.select_related('item')` in a query to load the related `Item`s efficiently, and work with `.only` to prevent loading all columns.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, thanks for your response. As regards your second comment, you made mention of ```self.item.paper``` , are you saying it should be like this ```paperitem = models.ForeignKey(self.items.paper)```.?

Comment: no, you make a `item = models.ForeignKey(Items, ...)`, and when you *need* the value for paper, you access it with `myitemsgotten.item.paper`.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem, thanks for your response. Seems you're not getting my point. I don't want to display my Boolean Field in my template, I want them to appear in my Django Admin.. so how do I place this code ```myitemsgotten.item.paper``` so as to inherit from my Items model. Only the paper object instead of the whole item class

Comment: then this is nothing the model needs to be concerned about, but the modeladmin. It would be bad code design to specify this in the model layer.

Comment: Any hint on how I could go about it please?